# Strongest known version of Baker's theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

The article I have checked for Baker's theorem is [Waldschmidt's](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~miw/articles/pdf/GDL/SemBxMSGB.pdf). But the article and the citations therein are from the time of '88. Question:

> What is the the strongest known lower bound for Baker's theorem on linear forms on logarithms?

Similarly for p-adic Baker.

Comment: The motivation(if it is required for answering) is for looking into Tijdemann's methods for Catalan conjecture. The p-adic part is added for curiosity.

Comment: Request for longer tags: Here, for instance, transcendental-number-theory does not fit.

Comment: That issue's already come up on meta; you can discuss it there if you like.  For now, transcendental-nt works.

Comment: Ok, I implemented your suggestion.

Comment: Wikipedia (article: Linear forms in logarithms) lists a version from 1993; no idea if that's been improved since then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a big difference between linear forms in *many* logarithms and in *two* (or three) logarithms. The first case is covered in the archimedean case by the work of E. Matveev; Matveev's original works are hard even to specialists but there is a very nice survey [Yu. Nesterenko, Linear forms in logarithms of rational numbers, in *Diophantine approximation* (Cetraro, 2000),  53--106, Lecture Notes in Math., 1819, Springer, Berlin, 2003. MR2009829  (2004i:11082)]. The $p$-adic case was mostly done by Kunrui Yu. The best estimate for the case of two logarithms, which is of importance because of Tijdeman's application to Catalan's equation, is given in [[M. Laurent, M. Mignotte et Y. Nesterenko, Formes linéaires en deux logarithmes et déterminants d'interpolation, *J. Number Theory* **55** (1995), no. 2, 285--321. MR1366574 (96h:11073)]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jnth.1995.1141). The latest news in the last direction (also in relation to Catalan's) are reviewed in [M. Mignotte, Linear forms in two and three logarithms and interpolation determinants.  *Diophantine equations*, 151--166, Tata Inst. Fund. Res. Stud. Math., 20, Tata Inst. Fund. Res., Mumbai, 2008. MR1500224  (2010h:11119)]

Comment: Very nice to have the references. Thanks Wadim!

Comment: You are more than welcome, Anweshi!